# $.on, click doesn't work when href attribute is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

```
<a href="">i am a link</a>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $("a").on('click', function(){
        console.log("the a link is clicked")
    })
</script>
```

doesn't print anything, when i click on the link.

Whereas, when i initialise `href` with `hash` symbol, it works.

this works,

```
<a href="#">i am a link</a>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $("a").on('click', function(){
        console.log("the a link is clicked")
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first code example will work fine, you just need to prevent the page refresh that is happening when the link is clicked:

```
<a href="">i am a link</a>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $("a").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // < stop the link behaviour
        console.log("the a link is clicked")
    })
</script>
```

That said, it is better practice to always include a value on the `href` parameter, even if it is just a `#` - but still use `preventDefault()` if it's needed.

Comment: While I also add a #, it's no longer necessary in HTML5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#placeholder-hyperlink

Comment: @DominicTobias It's not required, but IMO it's better practice as it makes it obvious that you haven't forgotten to add a value - it shows that you specifically intend for this link to go nowhere.

Comment: This is the right answer. The hash is hiding the original problem by prevent the page refresh, but `preventDefault` is what is needed.